# Issue setting currentTime in HTML5 video

Tags: javascript, html, video, html5-video

I have a video in the middle of my html. As you can see at first I haven't any source

```
<video id="videoPrincipal" src="" width="640" height="360" controls preload></video>
```

When I click a button I trigger a function that makes:

```
myVid = document.getElementById('videoPrincipal');
myVid.src = 'video.mp4';
myVid.play();
myVid.currentTime ='5';
```

The video starts playing correctly but I cant set the current time (and I made the same as we can see in http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_currenttime.asp)

It gives me the same error if I set the currentTime before calling the play function.

The error that shows me in the console is the following: "Uncaught InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable." (in the currentTime line) but when i search this problem I cant associate with video, only with canvas.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You don't have to wait for it to start playing, but it does have to be ready to play. There's the [canplay](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_event_canplay.asp) event to do that, so something like this should work:

```js
myVid.play();
myVid.addEventListener('canplay', function() {
    this.currentTime = 5;
});
```

Comment: That was driving me nuts. That's fixed it. Thank you.

Comment: This is great, and canplay is handled by all browsers that support the video tag.

Comment: Hey, do you know what's the corresponding event when autoplay happened? Do it happened after "canplay"?

Comment: It's probably just "play", which is when the video starts playing.

Comment: Setting `currentTime` triggers the `canplay` event so this example creates a loop.

Comment: Did anyone find a clean way to handle the loop this creates? This solution is not workable for me with that loop active.

Comment: @Methodician are you saying `addEventListener` is a loop?

Comment: You haven't mentioned which browser you're using, but if it's Chrome, you may be experiencing a bug. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1018533 (Similar bugs have been filed and closed numerous times over the years, because it apparently only occurs with some videos.) I've spent hours trying many different events, and it turns out the browser is just stuffed.

Answer (score 4):

As above mentioned, you try to set currentTime when the video is not seekable. So, as an alternative use-case (reset time to 0 when a user click on a button, for example), you can do something like:

```js
function resetVideo() {
  myVid.pause();
   
  if (myVid.seekable.length > 0) {
    myVid.currentTime = 0;
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you can also trying to reset only if the video has been played before.

```js
function resetVideo() {
  myVid.pause();
   
  if (myVid.currentTime !== 0) {
    myVid.currentTime = 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
video = document.getElementById('video');
begin_play  = 50;
play_video_first = true; //if you want to run only first time    
video.addEventListener("play", capture, false);

function capture(event) 
{
     if (event.type == "play"){
         if(play_video_first){
             play_video_first = false;
             video.currentTime = begin_play;
          }
     }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You have to wait until it's ready to play, 
i.e. don't expect `play` to be a blocking function 
Change your code as follows:

```
myVid.play();
myVid.media.addEventListener('playing', function(){
    myVid.setCurrentTime(5);
});
```