# Restrict audio playback to specified range

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

Say I have an audio file that is 90 seconds long.

I wish to load this audio file for user playback, but have the playback restricted between 10s-40s.

What I am trying to achieve:

- Audio starts at 10s
- When audio ends, it resets to the 10s mark
- Audio ends at 40s
- Audio outside the range is inaccessible

Comment: can you just edit the audio file before inserting it in your page ? javascript has the .currentTime method which will set it to 10s

Comment: I don't think that's possible.  At least it would be very difficult.  Just edit the audio before you upload it.

Answer (score 4):

Had a similar problem

Solution is as follows, this will drag the playback to the start of the segment if someone tries to select outside, and likewise do so at the end of the segment:

```
<audio controls ontimeupdate="restrictAudio(this)">
  <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">

</audio>
<script>
  function restrictAudio(event) {
    // Trying to stop the player if it goes above 10 second
    if (event.currentTime < 10 || event.currentTime > 40) {
      event.pause();
      event.currentTime = 10
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var startTime = 10;
var endTime = 15;

// Get our audio (could also get an audio element from the DOM)
var audio = new Audio('http://www.tonycuffe.com/mp3/cairnomount.mp3');

// Must start before we can set the time
audio.play();

// Must make sure audio is ready
// see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20240607/1968462
audio.addEventListener("canplay", function() {
    audio.currentTime = startTime;
});

// Every 1000ms (1 second), we check if we've exceeded the bounds and if so, we
// set the time back to the end.
setInterval(function(){
    if(audio.currentTime > endTime) {
        audio.currentTime = startTime;
    }
    console.log(audio.currentTime);
}, 1000);
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/bn66s67q/1/

Note that this is not a good approach. The user must download the entire file instead of just the truncated part. You should strongly consider truncating the file. You could even do the truncation server side with an audio editing library.

Also note that this isn't exact. I've added logging of the current time to the above example (view it in the JavaScript console). You'll note that you can be up to a second off. If you need precision, you could reduce the interval time.

The above code works in the latest versions of Firefox, Chrome, and IE (I did not test any others).

Answer (score -1):

```
<script>
var audiofile = document.getElementById("myAudio");
 var currenttime=  audiofile.currentTime;
 currenttime=10;
 if(currenttime>39){currenttime=10;}
</script>
```