# Jquery trigger function when video preview has loaded from blob

Tags: javascript, jquery, video

I have a function that allows users to select and upload a video form their computer or device, when the user selects a file it previews itself to user (images/videos). Function works fine for images but doesn't catch the load of the video. Does this still work if the video is loaded as blob and also if the html elements are created using javascript?

The code is something like this

```
function () {
   //first run file check restrictions
   //if no errors



 var chatW = $('#chatView #chatWindow');
        var parent = $('<li/>', { class : 'me', 'data-role' : 'none'});
        var pp = $('<div/>', {class : 'pp'});
        var msg = $('<div/>', { class : 'message file_' + type + '', 'data-date' : 'NEW DATE', id : 'chat_TEMPID' }); 
        switch(type){
            case 'image':
                var FR= new FileReader();
                FR.onload = function(e) {
                  msg.css('background-image', 'url(' + e.target.result + ')');
                };       
                FR.readAsDataURL( this.files[0] );
                ///handle the the upload
                var imageSize = readableSize(filesize);

                var loader = $('<div/>', {class : 'not_saved', 'data-size' : imageSize});
                loader.data('size', imageSize);
                loader.appendTo(msg);
            break;
            case 'video':
                var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
                var video = $('<video/>', { autoplay : false, src : url });
                video.appendTo(msg);
                function checkLoad() {
                    if (video.readyState === 4) {
                        video.currentTime = (10 / 29.97);
                        console.log('Video has loaded');
                    } else {
                        console.log('Not Loaded');
                        setTimeout(checkLoad, 100);
                    }
                }
                checkLoad();
                var loader = $('<div/>', {class : 'not_saved', 'data-size' : readableSize(filesize)});
                loader.data('size', readableSize(filesize));
                loader.appendTo(msg);
            break;
            case 'file':
                //and so on 
            break;
            case 'other':
                //and so on
            break;
        }
        pp.appendTo(parent);
        msg.appendTo(parent);
        parent.appendTo(chatW);

}
```

The problem I think is this part of the function:

```
case 'video':
                var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
                var video = $('<video/>', { autoplay : false, src : url });
                video.appendTo(msg);
                function checkLoad() {
                    if (video.readyState === 4) {
                        video.currentTime = (10 / 29.97);
                        console.log('Video has loaded');
                    } else {
                        console.log('Not Loaded');
                        setTimeout(checkLoad, 100);
                    }
                }
                checkLoad();
                var loader = $('<div/>', {class : 'not_saved', 'data-size' : readableSize(filesize)});
                loader.data('size', readableSize(filesize));
                loader.appendTo(msg);
            break;
```

The video does load in and if i set controls I can play the video. The check load function seams to run on a constant loop.

Full Code

```
var validateFileUpload = function () {
    var file = this.files[0];
    var type = file.type.split('/'); type = type[0];
    var filesize = file.size;
    if(type != 'video' && type != 'image' && type != 'text'){ type = 'other'; }
    var restrictions = {
        video : {
            size : 30000000, /* 30mb */
            warning : 'Videos should be less than 30MB in size'
        },
        image : {
            size : 15000000, /* 15mb */
            warning : 'Images should be less than 15mb in size'
        },
        text : {
            size : 5000000, /* 5mb */
            warning : 'Text files should be less than 5mb in size'
        },
        other : {
            size : 30000000, /* 30mb */
            warning : 'All other files should be less than 10mb'
        }
    };
    var readableSize = function (bytes){
        if(bytes == 0) return '0 Byte';
       var k = 1000;
       var dm = 1 || 3;
       var sizes = ['Bytes', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB', 'PB', 'EB', 'ZB', 'YB'];
       var i = Math.floor(Math.log(bytes) / Math.log(k));
       return parseFloat((bytes / Math.pow(k, i)).toFixed(dm)) + ' ' + sizes[i];
        if(filesize < 1000){
            return filesize + 'BTYES';
        } else if(filesize >= 1000 && filesize < 10000){
            return Math.round(filesize / 10000) + 'KB';
        } else {
            return Math.round(filesize / 100000) + 'MB';
        }
    }
    if(filesize > restrictions[type].size){
        makeToast(restrictions[type].warning);
    } else {
        var chatW = $('#chatView #chatWindow');
        var parent = $('<li/>', { class : 'me', 'data-role' : 'none'});
        var pp = $('<div/>', {class : 'pp'}); //add background image in here
        var msg = $('<div/>', { class : 'message file_' + type + '', 'data-date' : 'NEW DATE', id : 'chat_TEMPID' }); //change the temp ID after send
        switch(type){
            case 'image':
                //this will need changing to cordova function later
                var FR= new FileReader();
                FR.onload = function(e) {
                  //EL("img").src       = e.target.result;
                  //EL("b64").innerHTML = e.target.result;
                  msg.css('background-image', 'url(' + e.target.result + ')');
                };       
                FR.readAsDataURL( this.files[0] );
                ///handle the the upload
                var imageSize = readableSize(filesize);

                var loader = $('<div/>', {class : 'not_saved', 'data-size' : imageSize});
                loader.data('size', imageSize);
                loader.appendTo(msg);
            break;
            case 'video':
                var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
                var video = $('<video/>', { autoplay : false, src : url });
                video.appendTo(msg);
                function checkLoad() {
                    if (video.readyState === 4) {
                        video.currentTime = (10 / 29.97);
                        console.log('Video has loaded');
                    } else {
                        console.log('Not Loaded');
                        setTimeout(checkLoad, 100);
                    }
                }
                checkLoad();
                var loader = $('<div/>', {class : 'not_saved', 'data-size' : readableSize(filesize)});
                loader.data('size', readableSize(filesize));
                loader.appendTo(msg);
            break;
            case 'file':
                //and so on 
            break;
            case 'other':
                //and so on
            break;
        }
        pp.appendTo(parent);
        msg.appendTo(parent);
        parent.appendTo(chatW);
        //prepare uploader and cancel button
        var loading = $('<div/>',{ class : 'downloading'} );
        loader.after().on('click', function () {
            loading.remove();
            parent.fadeOut(250, function () {
                parent.remove();
            });
        });
        loading.appendTo(loader);
        loading.animate({'width' : '100%'}, 3000, function(){
            msg.removeClass('not_saved');
        });
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't start the video, then you need to load something. One solution is to use `preload="metadata"` and bind on the `loadedmetadata` event.

Example:

```
var aspectratio=1;
var video = $('<video/>', { autoplay : false, src : url, preload:'metadata' });
video.on('loadedmetadata',function() {
    var width = this.videoWidth;
    var height = this.videoHeight;
    aspectratio=width/height;
    console.log(aspectratio);
});
```

Comment: Thanks that was fast, works great. By any chance do you know why video.currentTime = (10 / 29.97); isnt changing the video to the tenth frame

Comment: Something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20240088/issue-setting-currenttime-in-html5-video ?

Comment: is there a jquery version on "canplay"

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_event_canplay.asp jQuery is binding on existing DOM events, there are no "jQuery version events".