# InvalidStateError in IE11 when trying to rewind and pause video

Tags: javascript, html5-video, internet-explorer-11, resolution, h.264

I am building a website where videos start to play when you move the mousepointer over them. When a user leaves the video area it pauses and jumps back to the first frame. This works perfectly in every browser besides IE. When I open the dev console it shows me an "InvalidStateError" right above the part of code that handles the stop function. Why is IE behaving like that? Thanks for any input on this.

Here is the part of code that triggers the error:

```
var figure = $('.servus_video').hover(playVideo, stopVideo);

function playVideo(e) {
    $('video', this).get(0).play();
}

function stopVideo(e) {
    $('video', this).get(0).currentTime = 0;
    $('video', this).get(0).pause();
}
```

[Screenshot from IE11 debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvCzc.jpg)

Comment: If you remove the line: $('video', this).get(0).currentTime = 0;   , does it work in IE? I think that this is what causes your problem (See:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20240088/issue-setting-currenttime-in-html5-video)

Comment: Thank you, this actually fixes the error but I can't get my head around how I could implement the "canplay" event listener, that is mentioned in your link, in my hover function. I really need to jump back to the first frame.

Comment: It doesn't even play in IE11 and I have no idea why. Searched the internet for hours but Haven't found a solution yet..

Answer (score 5):

Ok, after hours of troubleshooting I realized that IE responded with "Invalid Source" which I couldn't see because I disabled controls for the video. After tripple checking my encoder settings and verifying that they were correct I stumbled upon a document in which MS states that the maximum supported height of a video file is 1088px. 1088!? My videos were 720x1280px (portrait). After changing the resolution to 612x1088px everything worked.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd797815(v=vs.85).aspx